# Avoid adding/extending methods to interface

Tags: oop, design-patterns, interface

I have a scenario , where my current interface looks like

```
    public interface IMathematicalOperation
    {
         void AddInt();
    }
```

After an year i expect the interface to be extended with **AddFloat** method and also expect 100 users already consuming this interface. When i extend the interface with a new method after an year i don't want these 100 classes to get changed.
So how can i tackle this situation ? Is there any design pattern available already to take care of this situation ?

**Note:** i understand that i can have a abstract class which implement this interface and make all the methods virtual , so that clients can inherit from this class rather than the interface and override the methods . When i add a new method only the abstract class will be changed and the clients who are interested in the method will override the behavior (minimize the change) . 
Is there any other way of achieving the same result (like having a method named Add and based on certain condition it will do Float addition or Integer addition) ?

**Edit 1:**

The new method gets added to the interface also needs to be called automatically along with the existing methods(like chain of responsibility pattern).

Comment: why don't you extend it?

Comment: Isn't that a problem that 100 classes which implement this interface will get affected ? Hence wanted to avoid that issue.

Comment: No, they won't be affected. They rely only on the old interface.

Comment: Ok , i got what you meant by extending it . I assumed the extension means modification of old interface. I would like to rely on only one interface (as i am the provider , i need to call methods and i dont want to do a type check) , so i would liek to avoid a new interface and a new method getting added to it.

Comment: If you want to rely on the new interface, the classes *have* to implement the new function, so they have to change. I'd assume that you have a new context, where this new function is used, so expect the  new interface there, and use the old one otherwise.

Comment: I suggest you change your question according to your comment that you require the interface also to call the new methods automatically.

Comment: If you want to change your interface dynamically, then something is very wrong: you're misunderstanding meaning of interface itself. It's a contract, it should be set once and for all.

Comment: Yes , i understand that interfaces shouldnt be changed . But this is not true in all cases based on requirements in the future the interfaces tend to change. That is why i am trying to design it in such a way and thinking about overcoming the issue which might pop up in future even if a new functionality is required or added.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two possible solution I can think of:

- Derive your new interface from your old interface

  `public interface IMathematicalOperation
   {
       void AddInt();
   }
   public interface IFloatingPointMathematicalOperation : IMathematicalOperation
   {
       void AddFloat();
   }`
- Have simply a parallel interface which contains the new method and have all classes which *need* the new interface derive from it

I'd suggest the second solution, since I don't understand why you would want an established interface to change.

Comment: Yeah i thought about this solution also , but would like to avoid type check by adding/extending with new interface. Fine , my scenario is more like , i want an interface named IConverter with a method named ConvertToFormatX (). But with the time change i expect a new method called ConvertToFormatY() in some time but not now. Also when i wanted to call the method in the interface i want to chain the methods . I.e currently call only ConvertToFormatX and when the new method gets added call that too and if another one gets added call the third one too.

Comment: So what you want to do is either a pipe architecture (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(software)) or the decorator pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue some time ago and found the best way was not to try and extend an existing interface, but to provide different versions of the interface with each new interface providing extra functionality. Over time I found that was not adding functionality on a regular basis, may once a year, so adding extra interfaces was never really an issue.

So, for example this is your first version of the interface:

```
public interface IMathematicalOperation
{
    void AddInt();
}
```

This interface would then be implemented on a class like this:

```
public class MathematicalOperationImpl : IMathematicalOperation
{
    public void AddInt()
    {
    }
}
```

Then when you need to add new functionality, i.e. create a version 2, you would create another interface with the same name, but with a "2" on the end:

```
public interface IMathematicalOperation2 : IMathematicalOperation
{
    void AddFloat();
}
```

And the `MathematicalOperationImpl` would be extended to implement this new interface:

```
public class MathematicalOperationImpl : IMathematicalOperation, IMathematicalOperation2
{
    public void AddInt()
    {
    }

    public void AddFloat()
    {
    }
}
```

All of your new/future clients could start using the version 2 interface, but your existing clients would continue to work because they will only know about the first version of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

The options provided are syntactically viable but then, as is obvious, they won't apply to any previous users.

A better option would be to use the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

The pattern is best understood when you think about the details of OO code

```
this.foo(); // is identical to
foo(this);
```

Remember that there is always a hidden 'this' parameter passed with every instance call. 
What the visitor pattern attempts to do is generalize this behavior using [Double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)

Let's take this a hair further

```
public interface MathematicalOperation
{
    void addInt();
    void accept(MathVisitor v);
}

public interface MathVisitor {

    void visit(MathematicalOperation operation);

}

public class SquareVistor implements MathVisitor {

    void visit(MathematicalOperation operation) {
        operation.setValue(operation.getValue() * 2);
    }

}

public abstract class AbstractMathematicalOperation implements MathematicalOperation {
   public void accept(MathVisitor f) {
     f.visit(this); // we are going to do 'f' on 'this'. Or think this.f();
   }
}

public class MyMathOperation extends AbstractMathematicalOperation {

}

someMathOperation.visit(new SquareVisitor()); // is now functionally equivalent to
someMathOperation.square();
```

The best bet would be for you to roll-out your initial interface with a visitor requirements, then immediately roll-out an abstract subclass that gives this default implementation so it's cooked right in (As the above class is). Then everyone can just extend it. I think you will find this gives you the flexibility you need and leaves you will the ability to work with legacy classes.